# php files are not accessible, getting 404 status

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing strange problem. Only php files are not accessible through url. I am getting `status 404` error. Other files(html and image files) on the server are accessible.

All folders have permission - 755 and files have permission 644.

Here is my .htaccess file contents

```
AuthUserFile "/home/data/mysite/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
AuthName "SDA News"

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can any one help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: Are there any errors in your Apache error.log file? Most of the time there's a specific path it's trying to find and can't, which it will put into the log.

Comment: the ^index` business is kind of redundant. it'd get caught the `!-f` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "SDA News"
AuthUserFile "/home/data/mysite/.htpasswds/public_html/passwd"
require valid-user

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```